# MySql 8.0.22 resetting root password for windows

Tags: mysql, reset

I forgot my MySQL root password so I want to change password.
I tried this:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yeni-sifre';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and also I Watched a lot of video. I tried to clean mysql but it didn't. Please help me...

Comment: `--skip-grant-tables`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset root password in MySQL 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541700/reset-root-password-in-mysql-8)